# Process raw HTTP headers by HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, http-headers, httpclient

My client receive raw HTTP headers (including GET, POST, Multipart POST, etc.) and I want to send them to a server and get output.
But I don't want to parse whole request manually, then set all that parsed stuff to HttpClient...

Does an elegant way to do this (even something like code below)?

```
AGoodHttpClient response = new AGoodHttpClient(host, port, myHeaders);
InputStream in = response.getInputStream();
// ...
```

---

**Edited**

Let's say I have this code. How do I recognize EOS (`-1` isn't working for HTTP/1.1). Is there a guaranteed way how to cut the connection, when transfer is done? I want something what will care about cutting a connection (something like HttpClient), but with direct access to sending headers (like `outToServer.write(myHeaders)`).

```
 Socket connectionToServer = new Socket(host, port);
 OutputStream outToServer = connectionToServer.getOutputStream();

 outToServer.write(myHeaders.getBytes());

 InputStream inputFromServer = connectionToServer.getInputStream();
 byte[] buff = new byte[1024];

 int count;
 while ((count = inputFromServer.read(buff)) != -1) {
       System.out.write(buff, 0, count);
 }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: OK, but HTTP is keep-alive, so I have to recognize, when to stop => get Content-Length, but how, when I'm copying bytes(but not http response's lines)?

Comment: No, just copy the bytes, in both directions simultaneously. The keep-alive is end to end, nothing to do with you. When you read an EOS, shutdown the output in the other direction, and if you've already shutdown the output in the direction you got the EOS from, close the socket.

Comment: But I receive EOS only when server closes a connection. Am I right? (more questions are in the updated post)

Comment: that's right. You need two copying threads, one in each direction.